# Faster count(*) with pivot tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching, pivot, asmx

My problem is that in our application we do complex `SELECT` on our MS SQL Server (2008) database which is made ​​up of several joins (3 and more) to be used between the tables created using `PIVOT` (every pivot table has about 10 000 rows).

Only a `SELECT` is quite fast (select returns only a few rows from the total as 50 from 10, 000). But finding count of all records with `Count(*)` or filtering is much slower (for 10 000 records about 2 seconds)

Is there any way to speed up queries on the total number of queries and on filtering?
For example some caching in SQL Server or optimalization query?

Note: query to database made by our ASMX service.
Note2: Every table, which contains pivot has primary key type: uniqueidentifier

Base select looks like this:

```
SELECT
   Table1.[Id] AS [Id],
   Table1.[Status] AS [Status],
   Table2.[Id] AS [Id],
   Table2.[Status] AS [Status],

FROM 
(            
 -- Do PIVOT
 ) AS Table1
LEFT JOIN (            
 -- Do PIVOT
 ) AS Table2 ON Table2.xxx = Table1.yyy
 ) 

--Catch only first X records..
```

Comment: Sorry, of course I thing MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a View for each of your Pivot

From MS documentation

> After a unique clustered index is created on the view, the view's
>   result set is materialized immediately and persisted in physical
>   storage in the database, saving the overhead of performing this costly
>   operation at execution time.

Comment: Yes but i can't use materialized views because MSDN: The SELECT statement in the view definition must not contain the following Transact-SQL elements: PIVOT, UNPIVOT

Comment: Because of what ? I dont understand your comment, be more specific

Comment: There is constraint for select in Indexed views. Select can´t contain PIVOT, which I need use. There is all restrictions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx